# Highcharts errors when webpage in chrome background tab

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need some help with the following issue: it looks like since the latests Highcharts update (v7.0.2 2019-01-17), my pages are not working only when refreshing in background. If the webpage is always visible on my screen, everything will go smoothly, but if I have another chrome tab displayed on my screen, the update will not work and I will have this error:

```
highcharts.src.js:39446 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pos' of undefined
at a.SVGElement.step (highcharts.src.js:39446)
at a.SVGElement.animate (highcharts.src.js:3654)
at r.animate (highcharts.src.js:39437)
at r.x (highcharts-more.src.js:7599)
at r.a.(anonymous function) [as animate] (https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js:20:270)
at render (highcharts.src.js:35110)
at highcharts.src.js:28431
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at a.Chart.renderSeries (highcharts.src.js:28429)
at a.Chart.render (highcharts.src.js:28570)
```

The Javascript code for this chart is as follows:

```
Highcharts.chart('MychartID', {
  chart: {
    zoomType:'x',
    alignTicks: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    shared:false,
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Title'
    },
    xAxis: {
       type: 'category',
      title: {
        enabled: false,
        text: 'PTU',
      },
    },
    yAxis: [{
        lineWidth: 1,
        title: {
          text: 'y1'
        }
      },
      {
        lineWidth: 1,
        title: {
          text: 'y2'
        }
      },
      ],
     plotOptions: {
        line: {
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
          },
        },
        column: {
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
          },
        }
      },
    series: [
      {
        yAxis: 1,
        type: 'column',
        name: 'serie1',
        data: serie1
      },
      {
        name: 'serie2',
        data: serie2
      },
      ]
  });
```

Do you have any idea of what is going wrong?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you replicate this in a codepen/jFiddle and share it with us?

Comment: This issue may be caused by this fixed: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9749. However, we need reproduction to confirm that.

Comment: Good morning both, when you say you need reproduction to confirm that, do you mean you need something from me? the code I have displayed in my question is not enough?

Comment: @Nefarious62 Yes, please provide an isolated test case on https://jsfiddle.net or a similar site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was a bug and it is fixed. It will be available in the next release of Highcharts.

The solution before release is to use code from Highcharts GitHub master branch where this bug is solved. You can download it here: https://github.highcharts.com/master/highcharts.src.js